# wso2 Api gateway

Tags: encryption, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying find answers for few questions regarding wso2.

1. Does wso2 api gateway accept encrypted json message and have the capability to decrypt?
2. Does wso2 api gateway capable to call 2 Apis in a sequence? eg: can api gateway call Api1 and depending on the response call Api2.

I am not able to find these in any of the documentation. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Both of your requirements are possible with mediation sequences. You can implement the sequence as per your requirement and deploy them in APIM gateway.

Please refer the following documentation for,

1. Message mediation https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Mediating+Messages
2. Dynamic Endpoints https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Working+with+Endpoints
3. Adding mediation sequence to your API. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+Mediation+Extensions